# How to check the visibility of and load a dependency Dynamic Link Library (DLL) to the Kernel?

Tags: librarylink

I compiled (on Windows 10, using MinGW) a Dynamic Link Library that implements an interface to another one. I then use `LibraryLoad[dependencyDLL]` and then `LibraryFunctionLoad[interfaceDLL,...]` to expose a function to the Mathematica Kernel. When I try to use that function the Kernel crashes. That makes me suspect that the Wolfram Kernel cannot find the dependency DLL (which is not in my %PATH%).

I have no doubt that my interface is correct as everything above worked as intended on a Linux machine. I can confirm that my Windows compilation is correct as the test program (written in C) ran correctly.

How can I test if the Wolfram Kernel can see and load the dependencyDLL?

**Edit**

`FindLibrary[dependencyDLL]` outputs a path to the DLL. So Wolfram can see the library (if not, that would output a `$Failed`). Maybe its the interfaceDLL that cannot see its dependency?

**Edit: further info**

I could make it work on a Mac. Putting the dependency DLL on my PATH did not solve the problem (on Windows). I suspect it is something related to linking and other dependencies that I am unaware of (my dependecy DLL is provided by third parties).

I tried to build a minimal working example where I would reproduce that behavior. I could not...

The question remains: how can I see if the Kernel is crashing with a message of undefined reference or similar?

**Edit: further info 2**

The third party DLLs I am trying to use are intel's MKL. It seems that Mathematica has its own internal version of the MKL, thats why it did not crash on Linux and MacOS; but somehow the windows version is failing.

As per a comment: Using the Visual Studio compiler would be too much trouble as it does not comply to the C99 Standard, in which my code is based a lot (specially complex.h). I have no guarantee that these DLL are compatible with MinGW (gcc on Windows), but all pure C programs I've run so far on Windows did it without crashes. That's why I suspect it is a Mathematica side problem.

Comment: I would expect LibraryLoad and/or LibraryFunctionLoad to fail if there actually was a dependency problem

Comment: "I have no doubt that my interface is correct as everything above worked as intended on a Linux machine." That it appeared to work on Linux is actually no guarantee at all that you have no bug.

Comment: Dependencies must be explicitly loaded with `LibraryLoad`.  If you have a `mylib.dll` that uses the LibraryLink API, and depends on `otherlib.dll`, then you would first `LibraryLoad["othrelib.dll"]`, then use `LibraryFunctionLoad` (*not* `LibraryLoad`!) to load the functions from `mylib.dll`.

Comment: I do `LibraryLoad[dependency]` before `LibraryFunctionLoad[mylib]`. I've put further info...

Comment: On Unix-like systems, it helps to run the kernel in command line mode. It will often output something to the terminal when it crashes.  I do not know if this helps on Windows. If you try, try `math.exe`, not `MathKernel.exe`.  However, as Ilian said, a missing dependency should not cause a crash, and does not usually cause a crash.  Loading errors can be checked with ``LibraryLink`$LibraryError`` (but if the kernel crashes you obviously can't do that). To verify the dependencies of a DLL on Windows, use DependencyWalker.

Comment: Another idea: do you *need* to use MinGW? You could try the Visual Studio compiler. Are you sure that the 3rd party DLL you use does not require Visual Studio?  Suppose you try to `free()` memory that a function from this DLL allocated. That *would* cause a crash if there's a mismatch between malloc/free (e.g. VS vs MinGW or incompatible MinGW version).